# Dynamically accessed URL is not the same url stored in the database in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-datamapper

I am creating a cms where an user can upload an url with title. These URLs and titles, I am accessing dynamically in my front page of the website.
Suppose if I uploaded an url : www.google.com and title : google; then my front page displays the url : **http://localhost/project/index.php/www.google.com** and title : google

This is the foreach loop which I am running in my view page to display the url and title.

```
 <?php foreach($links as $a) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $a -> url; ?>" class="quicklinks"><b><?php echo $a -> url_title; ?></b></a>
 <?php } ?>
```

where echo **$a -> url;** is pointing to the **URL** column in the table and **echo $a -> url_title**; is pointing to the **url title column of the table**. I am using datampper for the DB Coding.
Please help me to display only www.google.com . Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: 1.  have you confirmed that the correct 'www.google.com' is being stored in the database?  2.  have you checked with firebug/chrome console what is actually being rendered on the page there?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response. Yes , it is storing perfectly in my database as www.google.com and when I am checking it with firebug it displays same as www.google.com but when I click on the link to open it goes to http://localhost/project/index.php/www.google.com . Please help me to find out the possible error. Thanks.

Comment: when I view the source of the page it displays following <a href="www.rediff.com.html" class="quicklinks">rediff</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add 'http://' in front of stored URL (if it doesn't contain this) or ammend your script to add 'http://' (or 'https://') to a submited link before inserting it into database.

For this you may utilize CodeIgniter's `prep_url()` function from URL helper:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: Thanks Aidas. Its working now. I need to change my code in my cms for valid url so that an admin can insert only valid url starting from http or https. You saved my time. Thank you soooooo much once again. :)